# troubleshooting why Internet Explorer keeps popping up in my start up?

Tags: internet-explorer-10

Internet Explorer keeps poopping up in my task bar. It is not set as my default browser. I have already ran a files clean up and a restore.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Please don't use all capital letters. I have cleaned up your post.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the appearance of internet explorer from the task bar,you can follow the below steps

(i) click on the start and then type internet explorer in the search programs and files.

(ii) Now right click on the internet explorer icon and chose unpin from the taskbar.

This would unpin from the task bar.